# Running different celery tasks (@shared_tasks) on different databases in django multi tenant application

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery

The application I am working on is a multitenant application. I am using celery to run background tasks.

The background tasks that get pushed to Queue (rabbitmq) are getting executed properly when run on the `default` db setting configured in the settings. But when I submit the background jobs from other tenants, i.e. settings other than `default` they fail. This is because, in normal sync flow, I am using a custom router that sets the DB to be used based on the request URL( which contains the tenant details). but the same context is lost when the job is submitted as a background task.

Any suggestions ?

I tried using transaction block and passing the db_name as below, but still, it is using the `default` database only

```
@shared_task
def run_background_task(task_id, db_name):
    with transaction.atomic(using=tenant_db):
        task = DPTask.objects.get(pk=task_id)
```

Ideally, the above query should get executed on `db_name` database settings, but it is happening on default only

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail e.g. which package you are using for multi-tenancy?

Comment: @kamran890 i am not using django-tenants. As my requirement was to have separate database rather than separate schema. 
I have written my custom db router

Comment: Alright! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **django-tenants**, a possible solution to achieve this would be to pass the tenant schema name as an argument to the task and set the schema context within the task.

```
@task(name="some_task")
def some_task(tenant_schema_name, arg1, arg2):
    with schema_context(tenant_schema_name):
        # Your task logic here
        ...
```

If you are working with multiple databases using some custom db router, then in same fashion as mentioned above, you can pass the tenant details to the task as an argument and set the db to be used within the task e.g. for transactions.

```
@task(name="some_task")
def some_task(tenant_db, arg1, arg2):
    with transaction.atomic(using=tenant_db)::
        # Your task logic here
        ...
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `using` on the used manager :

```py
@shared_task
def run_background_task(task_id, db_name):
    with transaction.atomic():
        task = DPTask.objects.using(tenant_db).get(pk=task_id)
```